# Simple way to Get filesize in x86 Assembly Language

Tags: linux, file, assembly

Assuming that I have opened a file in assembly and have the file handle for that file in register eax. How would I go about getting the size of the file so I can allocate enough buffer space for it?

I researched another discussion here that suggested using the `sys_fstat(28)` system call to get the file stats but couldn't implement it...

```
#My attempt at getting the file size

_test:  movl    filehandle, %ebx  #move filehandle (file descriptor) into ebx
        movl    $28, %eax         #fstat syscall
        int $0x80             # always end up with -14 in here not sure why
```

Comment: Where is the syscall going to put its results?

Comment: I was under the impression the results should go into eax unless there is an error?

Comment: The return value from the overall call goes there, yes, but the `sys_fstat` function doesn't return the size of the given file. It expects a second argument, a pointer to a `__old_kernel_stat` struct, which it populates with a number of pieces of information - only one of which is the file size.

Comment: File stats are a whole struct's worth of data.  That won't fit in EAX.

Comment: Ah, okay I see. Back to the drawing board for me then, thanks.

Comment: It's not a huge change.  Just have a chunk of memory in your data section that's as big as an `__old_kernel_stat`, and pass a pointer to it.  Once the call returns, that memory will have a bunch of info you didn't even know you wanted.  :)

Comment: Use the `stat` system call.

Comment: Do you mean fstat (28) or stat (18)?

Comment: "fstat is identical to stat, only the open file pointed to by a file descriptor (as returned by open(2)) is stat-ed in place of file_name." Up to you to decide which one fits in your application.

Comment: If I use fstat(28) or the new one newfstat(28) how do I find the size in the structure that is returned? Is there a manual for this stuff?

Comment: You'd find the definition for an `__old_kernel_stat`, which will probably be in the kernel headers (and probably written in C), and calculate the offset for whichever member represents the file size.  As for manuals, i dunno -- there might be.  But the kernel source/headers would be the ultimate authority.

Answer (score 2):

My solution  -- Just use .lcomm to create locations for all the named variables

```
movl    inputfile, %ebx         #Move file handler into ebx for system call
movl    $0x6c, %eax          #Stat Sys Call into eax
leal    statlocation, %ecx      #Move reserved location for stat structure into
int     $0x80                    #Execute System Call
movl    20(%ecx), %eax          #20 to location of size variable, size is now in eax
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how is implemented in FreshLib. It is a wrapper in order to provide portability. You can simplify it of course (see below).

```
  struct STAT
    .st_dev     dw  ?     ; ID of device containing file
    .pad1       dw  ?
    .st_ino     dd  ?     ; inode number
    .st_mode    dw  ?     ; protection
    .st_nlink   dw  ?     ; number of hard links
    .st_uid     dw  ?     ; user ID of owner
    .st_gid     dw  ?     ; group ID of owner
    .st_rdev    dw  ?     ; device ID (if special file)
    .pad2       dw  ?
    .st_size    dd  ?     ; total size, in bytes
    .st_blksize dd  ?     ; block size
    .st_blocks  dd  ?

    .st_atime   dd  ?     ; time of last access
    .unused1    dd  ?

    .st_mtime   dd  ?     ; time of last modification
    .unused2    dd  ?

    .st_ctime   dd  ?     ; time of last status change
    .unused3    dd  ?
    .unused4    dd  ?
    .unused5    dd  ?
  ends

  sys_newfstat =  $6c

  proc FileSize, .handle
  .stat STAT
  begin
          push    edx ecx ebx

          mov     eax, sys_newfstat
          mov     ebx, [.handle]
          lea     ecx, [.stat]
          int     $80

          cmp     eax, -1
          jle     .error

          mov     eax, [.stat.st_size]
          clc
          pop     ebx ecx edx
          return

  .error:
          neg     eax       ; error code
          stc
          pop     ebx ecx edx
          return
  endp
```

The minimal version can look this way (much less readable and not thread safe):

```
  ; argument: file handle in ebx
  ; returns:  the size in EDX; error code in EAX
  FileSize:
          mov     eax, $6c
          mov     ecx, file_stat
          int     $80
          mov     edx, [file_stat+$14]
          retn

  file_stat rd $10
```

Comment: Thanks...I figured it out as well, I'll post for the sake of having the AT&T syntax:

Comment: @user2499298 - Try to quit AT&T syntax. It really is not suitable for serious assembly programming. :)

Comment: Believe me I agree wholeheartedly but I use it because I want to see the symbols/line comments when debugging in gdb.

Comment: @user2499298 - quit gdb as well. ;) Use [EDB](http://codef00.com/projects#debugger) instead.